# How to select best/worst features in dataset for classification

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, feature-selection

I'm doing small random forest on javascript and i have a 2d array with features. Some of them are mostly pure noise and i would like to remove them from set. I'm stuck with understanding what i need to calculate for each feature to make some king of rating of worst features. And i find how to make it on R with library, but i need algorithm to implement it by myself...

inb4: i've read about Feature selection on wiki and it doesn't help much...
Thanks!

My dataset looks like this: (3 class and a some features)

[image: My dataset]

Comment: You mean you have a dataframe  with entities in rows and observations or "features" in columns and you wish to cull columns which won't help with discrimination?

Comment: I've added example in the post

Comment: You can also implement xgboost algorithm for feature selection: [Feature Importance and Feature Selection With XGBoost](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-importance-and-feature-selection-with-xgboost-in-python/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some important feature selection techniques

1) Linear regression with lasso penalty.    2) Random forest (either
    entropy or gini).   3) Forward stepwise selection.   4) Backward
    stepwise selection.   5) P value

There are many more feature selection techniques, in case your are working in python you could start reading http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html, where you would find code on using feature selection techniques.

Comment: Thank you very much for marking it as answer and upvoting.

Answer (score 3):

The point of using a feature to divide your set is that it helps in computing the final classification.  So, the *best* feature would be one that alone is enough to get the classification right, while the *worst* would be one that divides your dataset into subsets that are each no easier to classify than the original (actually, the VERY worst would be one that doesn't even divide it into subsets).

So you are looking for how "skewed" the subsets are that you get based on the feature; the more skewed, the better.

There are formulae that quantify this idea (something like P(1-P) as I recall), but I've got to leave *some* work for you.

Comment: Thank  you! So i need gini index i guess.

Comment: Just plot the data, feature by feature, label by label. Then you can eyeball which features are useful and which are not.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean can't do this. It should be made inside program because feature could be different. I don't use R for this.